# Adding referential integrity not on id/foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I have the `Course` model with 3 attributes: `instructor_id`, `year`, and `tag`.

If there a way to make a `course` with a `tag` invalid if there isn't an already defined `course` having the same value as `year` for the same `instructor_id`? 
For instance, with the following `courses` table.

```
|instructor_id|year|tag|
|1            |2019|   |
```

The following statements are all correct

```
Course.new(instructor_id: 1, tag: 2019).valid? #=> true
Course.new(instructor_id: 1, tag: 2020).valid? #=> false
```

Or should I write a custom validator for that?

To clarify, here my custom validator

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
      validates :tag,   referential_integrity: { reference: :year, scope: :instructor },
                        allow_nil: true
end


class ReferentialIntegrityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute, :required) unless record.class.find_by(options[:scope] => record.send(options[:scope]),
                                                                        options[:reference] => value)
  end
end
```

Can I achieve the same suing built-in validation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a validation like this or similar with year instead of tag

```
validates :instructor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:tag] }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My goal here is to make sure it's not possible to have a `course` (for an `instructor`) with a `tag` different from an existing `year`. I don't see how the `uniqueness` can guarentee so.